# Auto Focus in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a simple Chrome extension - search with a form.

When I open the extension, there is no default focus on form, but it requires additional click.

Focus is suppose to happen on popup.html form.

Now JavaScript `.focus()` method didn't work, Is there any other way to set default focus for Chrome extensions?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="mydata"  />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('mydata').focus();
```

Comment: It is suppose to happen on popup.html form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus()
{
     document.getElementById("target").focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">

<input type="text" id="target" name="target" size="25" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

the latest chrome has supported `tabindex` attribute. So you can use

```
<input type="text" id="mydata" tabindex="1" />
```

to make it work without any js codes. just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome supports [autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_autofocus_attribute) which doesn't require any JavaScript.

`<input type="text" id="mydata" autofocus />`

Comment: autofocus wont work in chrome extension up to version 23 (the last one ;)

Comment: Works on chrome 32, good enough for me https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121006

Answer (score 1):

The issue with chrome extensions is that the entire popup.html document has no focus by default. Therefore it's simply not enough to set the focus on an element. You first need to reload the page.

Just put the following code into the page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Init () {
            if (document.hasFocus)
                setInterval ("checkFocus ()", 300);
        }
        function checkFocus () {
            if (!document.hasFocus ()) {
                document.location.reload();
            }            
        }
    document.getElementById('mydata').focus();
    </script>
```

Then call the code in your body tag:

```
<body onload="Init ();">
```

That's it. 
Please keep in mind that this solution is just a work-around. May future chrome versions fix the focus issue in extensions to make this workaround superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setFocus(loc) {
    window.open(loc, 'popup1', 'height=655,width=710,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,minimizable=no').close();
    window.open(loc, 'popup1', 'height=655,width=710,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,minimizable=no').status.fixed();
}
```

Then:

```
lnkSongTitle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:setFocus('url')");
```

or in html `onClick` call `SetFocus() function`