# chrome extension popup textarea focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

It seems that i cannot call focus() on a textarea of my chrome extensions popup when it gets opened / after ondomready.

i have something like that in popup.js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   console.log($("#moped-text"));
   $('textarea').focus();   
   $('.container').css("color", "red");
});
```

i reference it in popup.html like that:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/content.css" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
       <div class="container">
            <textarea name="newText"></textarea>
       </div>     
 </body>
```

The css-change works, the focus() does not!

When i debug the popup and type $('textarea').focus(); in the console, it works.
Also events added inside the ready-callback are bound successfully.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: this isnt working for me neither: [Auto Focus in Google Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594064/auto-focus-in-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i still don't know, why the focus is not set at the first place, but a simple timeout does the job :)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#moped-text').focus();
}, 500);
```

Comment: This has always worked for me but in Chrome 18 (just made it to stable channel) this doesn't work. Even if I set the timeout to 1000 ms nothing happens. Do you experience the same thing, and if so do you perhaps know of a solution/workaround for the current situation?

Answer (score 3):

Workaround for Chrome 18 (found [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111660#c7))

```
if(location.search !== "?foo")
{
  location.search = "?foo";
  throw new Error;  // load everything on the next page;
                    // stop execution on this page
}
```

Works for me!

Comment: Wow, magic. I put this at the top of my popup.js and voila! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have div with class "container" not id. So use this instead:

```
$('.container').css("color", "red");
```

Comment: thanks hamczu! i changed my question accordingly. The css is not the problem, its the focus().

Answer (score 0):

I use this to focus.

My element has "autofocus" as an attribute. When the form is loaded, the element with the attribute "autofocus" gets the focus.

.directive('autofocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
        link : function($scope, $element) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $element[0].focus();
            });
        }
    }
}])

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `<textarea name="newText" autofocus></textarea>`.

Comment: this does not work either. seems to be blocked in chrome extensions.. :( or something else is getting the focus afterwards